# How to use context-path in Grails 3.0.9

Tags: grails, port

In Grails 3.0.9, I want to change the port for `run-app`, I have modified `application.yml`:

```
server:
    port: 9000
    context-path: '/@info.app.name@'
```

then I run-app, this is the result:

http://localhost:9000/@info.app.name@

why is it not the name of project?

Comment: i believe by default it's the name of project in context-path. the context path.try filter token as  {} .Also try removing / from context-path.

Comment: ContextPath must start with '/ and not end with '/'